# Setting background colour of contact form 7 submit button not correct

Tags: contact-form-7

I have seen a few questions and also searched the internet. It sounds like the answer to this question should be simple.

Here is my contact form:

http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/contact-form/

I am using the Contact Form 7 plugin.

My issue relates to the Submit button. I have used "Additional CSS":

```
.wpcf7 input[type="submit"]
{
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #eeeeee!important;
    color:black;
}
```

But the result is like this:

[image: Submit]

But that is not right. It should be like this:

[image: Submit 2]

Why is this happening?

---

I have added more CSS to size the botton and add rounded corners. Also hover effect. But my colours are still not being honored.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `id` for the Submit button then provide the CSS for that `id`:

```
input#id
{
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #eeeeee!important;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Sure. In my specific case it was because the theme itself was applying some kind of shading to all colours. So it was massaging my colours into new ones. I am not sure what they changed but it is now ok.